# RPlidar could not be launch

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am now doing a project using RPLidar in ubuntu 16.04. However, I am facing some problem with running the RPLidar. I have checked that my `userid` is inside the `dialout` group. The below code is what I receive after launching the `roslaunch rplidar_python rplidar.launch`. The rosdistro I am using is Kinetic and the reversion is 1.12.14.

```
process[rplidar-1]: started with pid [10922]
[INFO] [1558528578.411324]: initialization system
[WARN] [1558528578.449588]: find rplidar connect on port: /dev/ttyUSB0
[WARN] [1558528578.451918]: connect port: CP2102 USB to UART Bridge Controller
[INFO] [1558528578.452421]: sending commands
[INFO] [1558528578.453045]: evaluating header
[INFO] [1558528578.464362]: health status: status_ok
[INFO] [1558528578.465156]: sending commands
[INFO] [1558528578.465766]: evaluating header
```

The python node is running, but the RPLidar is not scanning. Can anyone help and solve this problem?

Comment: What is *RPlidar*?

Comment: Which version of RPLIDAR hardware do you have? Have you tried the official tutorials from http://wiki.ros.org/rplidar , to make sure your physical setup is correct?